# Weld 2.0.Final, Tomcat 7 and JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, weld2

At the moment we use the above combination, with the exception that we are still on JSF 2.1.
But I do miss the View Scope very strong in the CDI environment, I tried to update to JSF 2.2 while keeping the rest in place.

Now I encountered several problems with the javax.faces.view.ViewScoped. Views are dropped even if the ViewId didn't change, and other strange effects.

Now, I wonder if the choosen combination is valid at all. Does Weld 2.0 support JSF 2.2 and vice versa ?